# genRandomClust does not seem to be generating random clusters

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have been trying to generate som random clusters using the package clusterGeneraion. I keep getting the same output in terms of class distribution and the same clusters using kmeans. This is the code:

```
library(factoextra)
library(clusterGeneration)

nclust = 3
feat = 3

data = genRandomClust(numClust=nclust,
                        sepVal=-0.1, numNonNoisy=feat,
                        clustszind=2)

data = as.data.frame(cbind(data$datList$test_1, data$memList$test_1))
colnames(data)[feat+1] = "class"
table(data$class)

km.res <- eclust(data[,-(feat+1)], "kmeans", k = nclust, nstart = 25, graph = FALSE)
table(km.res$cluster, data$class)
```

which always gives me the following

Classdistribution

```
  1   2   3 
 77 102 153
```

Clusters from kmeans

```
      1   2   3
  1   4  81   1
  2  70   7  14
  3   3  14 138
```

Why are these not random?

Comment: In the `eclust` documentation it looks like the default is to set a seed, `seed = 123`, so you probably need to manually change this to get another set of clusters.

Comment: Setting the seed to be random solved the problem, thanks!